# Implement and override is not happening from supertype

Tags: java, jersey

Right now I am wring interface and implementingt the interface for that, and I am facing the following issue. Could any body solve what may be the problem with this code .

```
public interface TokenValidateApi {

  String URI_API_TOKEN = "/api/rcsAccessCheck/";

  ResponseBuilder validateIDMToken(String token);

  Response createProductInJSON();
}
```

here is the my implementation class, Right now i am facing the following "method does not override or implement a method from a supertype"

```
@Component
@Path("/rcsAccessCheck")
@Api(value = "/rcsAccessCheck", description = "The token validation is for IDM Token validation. (internal use only)")
public class TokenValidateApiImpl extends RestEndpoint implements TokenValidateApi {

    @Autowired
    private IdmRequestTokenProvider requestTokenProvider;

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/validateToken")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Returns the Token Authenticatication response")
    @ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "The validate token service doesn't exist."),
                        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Authorization failure")})
    @Override
    public ResponseBuilder validateIDMToken(@HeaderParam("IDMToken") String token) {
        System.out.println("Print the IDM TOKEN FROM RCS WAR:::::"+token);
        AuthenticationSuccessResponse response = requestTokenProvider.validateToken(token);

        return Response.ok(response);

    }

    @GET
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Override
    public Response createProductInJSON() {

        System.out.println("comes HErs");
        //String result = "Product created : " + product;
        return Response.status(201).build();

    }
 }
```

Comment: which method? they both look fine here to me

Comment: Try removing the parameter annotation within your class. Or adding the annotation within the interface.

Comment: Please add your "RestEndpoint" class

Answer (score 1):

Place your annotations on interface as well as on it's methods. And then just simply override its methods in class. May be it will work.